# Retrieve records which one field value doesn't end with space

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The database in question is MS SQL. I have this table and this field in varchar data type.

The field contains values such as:

> ```
> 1. " ABC DEF"
> 2. "ABC DEF "
> 3. " ABC DEF "
> 4. " CCC DEF "
> 5. " CCC DEF"
> ```

The double quotes are just used to show empty spaces in the values.

Now, how do I retrieve all records where this field doesn't end with an empty space? I thought the following SQL should work, but it doesn't!

```
    SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyField like '%DEF'
```

It retrieves all the above records. A working SQL should only retrieve records 1 and 5.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE '.' + LTRIM(MyField) + '.' = '.' + RTRIM(LTRIM(MyField)) + '.'
```

I guess this is not the correct way but this will give the expected output

Comment: Works perfectly! I just need a quick way to retrieve the records which satisfies the condition, ad hoc thing. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
  SELECT * FROM yourTable where yourField LIKE "% "
```

or `NOT LIKE`, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use This,

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE PATINDEX('%[ ]',[MyField]) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

WHERE LEN(RTRIM(myField)) = LEN(myField)

Comment: This may work, but in my case, comparing LEN might not be accurate, because the field can have values with the same length too.

Answer (score 0):

The len function ignores spaces at the end so you need to do something like add the . at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable where LEN(MyField) = DATALENGTH(MyField)
```

[LEN and trailing spaces](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/en/book_function_len_trailing_spaces_and_uniqueness.html)